# Why can some holodeck matter leave the holodeck, while other holodeck matter (notably people) cannot?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, holodeck

Related to [Would Star Trek holodecks physically affect you once you exit the Holodeck?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/8723/23159)

I was watching [Elementary, Dear Data](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Elementary,_Dear_Data_%28episode%29) last night and I noticed that when Data realizes that something has gone terribly wrong, he leaves the holodeck with the holodeck generated paper with a drawing of the Enterprise. The paper does not disintegrate as he leaves the holodeck. If this can leave the holodeck, why can't Professor Moriarity? Indeed, the original ending to this episode according to Memory Alpha:

> The original ending filmed was cut from the episode. (Star Trek: The Next Generation Companion 2nd ed., pp. 68-69) Hurley recalled, "In that ending, Picard knew how to defeat Moriarty. He tricked him. He knew all along that Moriarty could leave the holodeck whenever he wanted to, and he knew because when Data came out and showed him a drawing of the Enterprise, if that piece of paper could leave the holodeck, that means that the fail-safe had broken down. In turn, this means that the matter-energy converter which creates the holodeck, now allowed the matter to leave the holodeck, which was, up to that point, impossible. When he knew that paper had left the holodeck, he knew that Moriarty could as well, so he lied to him."

This is interesting because the whole premise of this episode and Ship in a Bottle is that Moriarity can't leave the holodeck. Moreover, the Doctor from Voyager always needs some kind of [portable emitter](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Mobile_emitter) to go places.

Given this and the water/other matter that leaves the holodeck in the [linked question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/8723/23159), **why can some matter exist outside the holodeck while other matter cannot?**

Is it tied somehow to the replicator - i.e. replicating a piece of paper into real matter is trivial, but replicating a human being or anything more sophisticated would be non-trivial?

Comment: The answers don't really answer why the Voyager crew was able to use the holodeck when on severe power rationing (and emergency food rations / Neelix-food) while using the holodeck much too often. In-universe discontinuity perhaps.

Comment: Note that you can see an example of why this is true in an earlier episode: The Big Goodbye. In it, Picard exits the holodeck with a lipstick print on his face, but in the very same episode the character Cyrus Redblock dematerializes shortly after he exits the holodeck.

Comment: The thing is, Moriarty isn't some replicated piece of matter. He's an interactive computer simulation that needs controlling. You can't 3D print a person.

Comment: "You can't 3D print a person" - Well, not *yet*...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The was actually addressed in one of the comments to the linked question.

From http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Holodeck#Design

> A holodeck combines transporter technology with that of replicators, by generating actual matter, as well as projecting force fields to give the objects the illusion of substance.

There are different reasons proposed for having both, one of them is that anything ingestible MUST be real matter (otherwise the user would have negative health effects after ingesting and leaving the Holodeck); another is that it's cheaper/easier to replicate some matter (e.g. water, or any such dynamic matter) than to fully computer-simulate and then holographically generate it.

On the other hand, as you noted, replicating a human is a whole lot more of a big deal that holographically project one.

Comment: The corollary is, of course, that humans cannot be replicated; the technology is limited to inanimate objects. Living things can of course be projected, and made to look and act real, but they are true holograms.

Comment: I don't know that I really buy the "processing power to generate a convincing hologram of water" argument. I mean, computers today can create *insanely* convincing water... there is no doubt in my mind that the computers of the 24th century would be able to make holographic water that was visually perfect. A more convincing argument, in my mind, would be that if someone falls in the water, they need to actually get wet... which holographic water would not do.

Comment: Add they _do_ get wet when they fall in water. It was mentioned in one of the episodes (Encounter at Farpoint perhaps?) that when Data fell in water on the holodeck it took a long time to get all the water out of him.

Comment: @Xantec, IN E@F it was Wesley who fell into a pond. But yes, he stayed wet when he left the holodeck. http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Holodeck

Comment: The water stayed because it was simple/small enough that it could be replicated.

Comment: Am I the only one that remembers that Quark offered, at an extra charge, replicated food in his halosuits?  I would presume something Quark charges for, that is legal, is free in a Federation holodeck...

Comment: Probably the programmer can decide that, by specifying which things can be taken off the holodeck.

Comment: Obviously, objects which impact the user (for example water absorbed by the body) has to be replicated, unless safety settings prohibit that of course.

Comment: @Tritium21 DS9 was only run by the Federation, it actually belonged to the Bajorans. Outside of the Federation there still is a capitalistic system similar to ours.

Answer (score 17):

This issue was specifically addressed in the "[Star Trek : Voyager Technical Manual](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Voyager_Technical_Manual)" handed out to potential scriptwriters for the Voyager series.

Simply put;

- Anything that people are likely to interact with (props, food, clothing, etc) is created by using a [matter-replicator](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Replicator).
- Anything that visitors are unlikely to interact with (or that doesn't require *physical texture*) is created using a coloured [forcefield](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Force_field).

> ***How it works:***
>
> *The Holodeck uses two main subsystems. the holographic imagery
> subsystem and the matter conversion subsystem. The holographic imagery
> system creates images of incredibly realistic background
> environments. The computer-driven holographic projectors also control
> a series of shaped-field forcebeam projectors which are capable of
> giving physical substance to these images. The second major subsystem
> is the matter conversion system. Using transporter-based technology,
> this system creates physical "props" and "set dressing" from raw
> material. Under normal conditions, a participant in a holodeck
> simulation should be unable to tell the difference between the two
> types of props.*
>
> ***The Holodeck and the reality of objects:***
>
> ***Objects created on the holodeck which are pure holographic images cannot be removed from the holodeck, even if they have apparent
> physical reality because of focused force beam imagery.***
>
> ***Objects created by transporter matter conversion do indeed have physical reality and can indeed be removed from the holodeck, even
> though they may no longer be under computer control.***

Comment: Yet the EMH fits neither mode by that description!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - We know from canon descriptions that he's wholly force-field based. It's not that close-up objects can't be made out of forcefields, it's just that there's no point wasting the energy of replicating something real if you can trick people with an effect.

Comment: Yet he has physical texture and can be interacted with.

Comment: @lightnessracesinorbit - I refer you to my previous answer. You can make complex stuff out of fields, it's just harder.

Comment: Why do chairs fall into the category of requiring a force field as opposed to being replicated like musical instruments and other similar objects created in other episodes?  Chairs supposedly could not be removed from the holodeck in the Ship in a Bottle episode.  Clearly the pattern for complex objects like chairs must exist in the replicator pattern database.  Also, regardless of the method used to create any object in the holodeck, all objects must disintegrate upon shut down of a holodeck program without distinction.  Why does the program running let paper leave, but not chairs?

Comment: @richardfairhurst - Dunno. Maybe because they have a very simple smooth texture or possibly because of the need for them to be stronger than real chairs?

Comment: Since the entire technology is imaginary, I suppose it only needs to adhere to those laws of physics that support a dramatic story line.  Real physics is frequently set aside in filmed entertainment when it disobeys that principle, as Mythbusters has repeatedly shown.

Comment: I'd also note that often the characters are shown to take their *own* instruments etc. It may also be that a holographic instrument doesn't have quite the same acoustic properties as, say, a wooden one. The point seems to be that things are projected or replicated as is most sensible at that moment in time - water in the distance may be CGI, water you're about to drink or fall into may be replicated.

Comment: @JonStory - I suspect that's more to do with familiarity with the instrument. Note that Picard has his own saddle that he takes to the holodeck.

Comment: I was more pointing out that the instruments may not be replicated on the spot then taken away from the Holodeck, but rather are personal possessions and brought to the Holodeck - therefore the "Replicated or projected" question doesn't apply. But yeah, I imagine 23rd Century people would still be attached to favoured possessions as we are now.

Answer (score 4):

The very first time a holodeck appeared in live-action Trek -- way back in the pilot episode of TNG, *[Encounter at Farpoint](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Encounter_at_Farpoint_(episode))* -- Data clearly indicated that holodeck programs employ a combination of holograms and real matter.

> **Riker:** "I didn't believe these simulations could be this real."
>
> **Data:** "Much of it *is* real, sir. If the transporters can convert our bodies to an energy beam, then back to the original pattern..."
>
> **Riker:** "Yes, of course; then these rocks and vegetations have much simpler patterns."
>
> **Data:** "Correct, sir."

Naturally, actual holograms like Moriarty and the Doctor can't exist in environments where there are no holo-emitters, but real matter can, regardless of whether it's been transported, or replicated, or whatnot.