# How could anyone make use of a holographic music chip?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, holodeck, hologram

In the opening of [*The Siege of AR-558* episode](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Siege_of_AR-558_(episode)):

> Dr. Bashir (...) retrieves a recording Vic has made for him to give to the Starfleet soldiers on AR-558.

How could that be possible? How could Bashir take virtual ("made of photons and energy"), non-existing in real world music chip out of holosuite? How could it be transported to AR-558? How could AR-558 soldiers make any use of it?

I thought that mobile emiters were invented (and shown) in *Voyager* serie only and that they were designed for a bit more important purpose (like having the only doctor aboard to travel outside ship) then using it as today music pendrive.

Wouldn't it be easier to simply download this music out of holosuite memory to any storage chip?

I don't know, what am I missing, but for me this tiny and irrelevant part of  [*The Siege of AR-558* episode](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Siege_of_AR-558_(episode)) simply is an absolute non-sense.

Comment: It says Vic gave him the recording, not the physical chip...

Comment: @BrianOrtiz That's what Memory Alpha, cited here, says. In actual episode an actual physical thing (chip, rod, anything) is clearly seen as been exchanged between Vic and Bashir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The script indicates that Vic recorded the recordings onto a *station-issue isolinear rod*.

> **BASHIR:** *Did you get a chance to make those audio recordings for me?*
>
> Vic nods and reaches into his jacket pocket, takes out an isolinear
> rod.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Siege of AR-558 - Screenplay](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/558.txt)</sup></sub>

Given that Vic apparently has access to the holosuite controls, it's likely that Bashir left the chip for him to use, Vic waited until the holosuite was clear, inserted the rod into the wall-console, ordered the computer to record audio for an hour, then collected it after he'd made the recordings.

Alternatively, and bearing in mind that holodecks are [capable of replicating matter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8946/why-can-some-holodeck-matter-leave-the-holodeck-while-other-holodeck-matter-no), it's possible that he simply ordered the computer to record audio for an hour, *replicate* an isolinear rod and transfer the results to it.

Comment: Point of fact... Isolinear rods (cylinders) are Cardassian, not Starfleet. Starfleet uses "chips" (rectangular, relatively flat).

Comment: @T.J.L. - That's a fair point. See edit.