# Why wasn't Dr. Pulaski beamed off the holodeck?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, holodeck

In [TNG: Elementary, Dear Data](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Elementary,_Dear_Data_(episode)), Dr. Pulaski is held hostage on the holodeck by Moriarty.

**Why don't they just beam her off the holodeck?**

Comment: Dr Pulaski hated transporters.

Comment: More to the point, there had been previous in-universe references to the hazards of beaming someone out of an active holodeck program.

Comment: Doesn't Moriarty's control of the computer mean he can negate any attempt to beam her or anybody on/off/around the ship?

Comment: @MrLister: I would consider Dr Pulaski's opinion a valid blanket refusal (some people wonder if the transported person is actually still the same person or a reconstitued clone with an identical memory - thus killing the original); except that I remember her taking a transporter once or twice when the situation called for it. If she thinks (or even simply can't disprove) that transporters essentially kill and clone you, she would _never_ take one. So I don't think her non-universal apprehension of transporters is a valid reason to not save her life in this particular scenario with Moriarty.

Comment: @Flater I remember an episode where she was dying of a disease that made her age rapidly, and the only way to save her was by transporting her. She did consent in the end, but she resisted the idea for quite a while. And no one on board the ship was willing to just do it against her will in the name of saving her life, either.  If 24th century ethics prevent people from using objectionable means to save the life of someone who is **definitely going to die, and soon** then I don't see why they'd permit for rescuing that person from *potential harm* if they might yet be saved by other means.

Comment: @Steve-O: IIRC the episode with Picard's heart operation, she also transported down due to the urgency, where her own life was thus not at stake. That would open the door to "rescue transporting" her more so than in your example.

Comment: @Flater So by your reckoning, the fact that someone consents to an act *once* means they can never refuse on moral grounds in the future?

Comment: @Steve-O: No, I'm saying it provides a reasonable justification for rescuing said person _in cases where they are not in the capacity to explicitly consent_. It's not a carte blanche, it's just a reasonable assumption on the rescuer's part in absence of the ability to ask for consent. There are _plenty_ of cases where people have been transported to save their lives without them expecting (and thus also not consenting) to be transported.

Comment: @Flater I suppose we'll have to agree to disagree on that point.

Comment: There's nothing in the script (nor retroactively insightful in the second Moriarty episode "Ship in a Bottle") that indicates they could not transport her off the holodeck, nor that they even thought of it. @ZeissIkon - which episode are you referencing re: dangers of off holodeck transport?

Comment: @NKCampbell If I'd remembered that, I'd have posted it as an answer.  I wasn't a regular watcher of TNG when it was on TV, and haven't watched many episodes in reruns, but I do recall mention (during another "trapped in the holodeck" episode) that it was hazardous to transport someone out of an *active* holodeck program.  This was likely because holodeck itself uses transporters to make the (fairly small) holodeck chamber seem infinite.

Comment: I don't recall any statement to that effect @ZeissIkon - will research further

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A similar situation occurs in [TNG: The Big Goodbye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Goodbye) when Picard and some underlings get trapped inside a Dixon Hill holonovel. Wesley explains that **mucking around with the holodeck is potentially fatal when the system is on the blink**. The system could "abort" and the people inside might disappear entirely. It's not made clear quite why this would happen, but we do know that the computer routinely disposes of any replicated material that's inside the holodeck when it's turned off. It's possible that the *'holodeck safeties'* are specifically intended to prevent people from (metaphorically) getting taken out with the trash but that when they're malfunctioning the computer might read the people on the holodeck as merely blobs of matter waiting to be recycled into feedstock.

> **RIKER:** *Forget the explanation! Can you repair it?*
>
> **WESLEY:** *I don't know if I should. **If this isn't done correctly, the program could abort and everyone inside could vanish.***
>
> **RIKER'S COM VOICE:** *Do you need more time to study it?*
>
> **WESLEY:** *No, sir. Whether we do it now or later, the risk will be the same.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Original Screenplay - TNG: The Big Good-bye](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/113.txt)</sup></sub>

Since Moriarty has done (unspecified) things to the computer, it's possible that
a failed transport attempt would present a similar risk to Pulaski.

Comment: I don’t recall Wesley saying beaming them off was a problem. His repair operation is what was risky.

Comment: @Craig - Oops. Sorry, yes. I've added a rider. Better?

Answer (score 0):

Moriarty would have had to set up a means to block the transporter. No such indication was made on the bridge. How often have we heard in episodes, "Transporters are offline"? Or, something to the effect of, "We cannot beam her off the holodeck". Face it, this **was** a mistake in the plot - dialog to not have someone, at sometime, exclaim, "Moriarty has set up a transporter scrambler, and if we try to beam anyone in or out their molecules will..." or "He has control of the holodeck matrix so..." etc.

Just because someone has control of the computer system does not mean they took every aspect of command and control over. Moriarty had the goal of getting the attention of Captain Picard, which he did. Let's not even go into simply locking onto just *any* lifeform, or getting a skeletal lock on someone (done in *Voyager*), and I am sure Data could have come up with another means to beam any *lifeform* off the holodeck. The writers just missed the one needed line to justify the crew's inability to just beam Dr. Polaski off the holodeck. Because backgrounds were fading in and out did not mean transporters would be ineffective - they did not say so in **this** episode. You cannot relate a previous episode's transporter issues to the new malfunction (accidental creation of a consciousness) to the same malfunction.

If that is not a mistake... then why couldn't they beam the chair off the holodeck in "Ship in a Bottle"? If they can walk off the holodeck with an inanimate object like the piece of paper, the chair should have been able to be removed. Why did the book disappear that Picard threw through the exit? You can't have it both ways. Either inanimate objects of paper, books, chairs, etc. *can* be removed from the holodeck, or they *can't*. If, as is suggested, replicated material can be removed, then the book and chair should also have been able to go through the exit.

Comment: This feels like guesswork. *"Moriarty would have had to set up a means to block the transporter"* doesn't explain why they don't beam people off of the holodeck in other episodes in the same franchise.

Comment: You might also want to have a read of [Why can some holodeck matter leave the holodeck, while other holodeck matter (notably people) cannot?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/55109/20774)