# What happens to matter (e.g. bodily fluids) that are left on the holodeck?

Tags: star-trek, holodeck

We know that [some of the matter generated on a Holodeck can actually leave the Holodeck's confines](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8946/why-can-some-holodeck-matter-leave-the-holodeck-while-other-holodeck-matter-no). For example, [you can spill "holodeck" water on someone and they will be wet outside](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8723/would-star-trek-holodecks-physically-affect-you-once-you-exit-the-holodeck).

But what happens when this happens in reverse? If someone brings some liquid INTO a Holodeck? What happens to it?

More specifically, if someone leaves some bodily fluids (e.g. gets a cut and their blood spills, or gets so drunk at the bar that they throw up), **what happens to those bodily fluids**?

Are they somehow processed/disposed of/transported away by the Holodeck?

Do they just hang around and fall to the floor once the holoprogram finishes?

Other?

Comment: Cleanup - holosuite six!

Comment: What happens on the Holodeck, stays on the Holodeck.

Comment: Thanks for making the earlier question more generic and less crude.

Comment: Red shirts are given a choice... travel to the planet with Kirk, or clean up the holodeck.

Comment: Sounds like a job for Starfleet's enlisted corps.

Comment: "ugh... looks like Ensign Lahmer has been exploring his Orion Slave Girl collection again...."

Comment: Starfleet Roombas!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The holodeck is an advanced application of transporter/replicator technologies. Much of what you see is real, solid matter that is generated by the controlling computer (and not a hologram).

When the program ends, the entire scene is "dematerialized", except for the people and their accouterments. Anything left behind, such as perspiration, dead skin cells, or any other bodily fluids would also be "dematerialized" and thus there would be no need for cleanup.

Comment: Source/cite please?

Comment: @DVK [Your own answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/8948/2242) (on another question)  =^_^=

Comment: -1: The holodeck being able to dematerialize things it didn't create in the first place is a pretty dangerous capability. While transporter-based technology (like replicators) certainly can destroy things (lookup Transporter Code 14), having it be standard procedure sounds risky... and a great way to murder somebody or destroy other evidence. I would instead expect the holodeck to be strongly designed to *not* damage or destroy anything it didn't create. Sure, these things break all the time because it makes good TV, but that doesn't mean it should be a standard feature. Also... no references.

Answer (score 11):

I would assume, since safety protocols are engaged, if someone gets cut and starts bleeding, the wound and subsequent blood and fluids would be holographic.

But for things like sweat and skin cells I would think it would remain on the holodeck floor after deactivation where whoever/whatever is responsible for keeping the Enterprise in its immaculate state takes over and cleans up the mess.

Which makes holo-porn just a bit more ewww than I want to admit...

Comment: Source/cite please?

Comment: @DVK - Words like "I would assume" and "I would think" mean that the answer is probably based off of the poster's best guess.

Comment: This would be my best guess as I have yet to find anything citeable on this specific issue. But, basing my evidence on the non-caring attitude towards what remains in the holodeck, It must be assumed that the solution for that problem is something ubiquitous to the individual user and therefore a nonissue for users in general. No one seems to care who CLEANS anything on the Enterprise (as no one is ever seen doing it) so it must be done in a way outside the "my problem" radius of an individual person.

Comment: This also raises other questions like "Where is the head?", "is there a Starfleet janitorial corps?" and, "If it's a waterless shower, why do people wrap into towels after?"

Comment: In TNG: Evolution, Wesley was asked why he was distributing traps, since the environmental system are supposed to keep the ship neat & tidy. (Of course, the traps were not for rats and the like, but for nanites). It seems that Starfleet ships clean themselves automatically.