# Can I be hungry on a Holodeck?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, holodeck

If I eat or drink on a holodeck will I be stuffed? And if so, if I leave the holodeck, will I be hungry again?

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8723/would-star-trek-holodecks-physically-affect-you-once-you-exit-the-holodeck

Comment: The answers on the other question explain that a matter replicator is used to create objects like food on the holodeck.